# Installing Elementary OS in Parallels gives blank screen

Tags: system-installation, virtualization

I am trying to install eOS under Parallels Desktop 14 on a late 2014 iMac running High Sierra (10.12). The Mac and Parallels are up to date.

While installing under Parallels, I create a custom config where I give the VM more RAM and more graphics memory. When done, it seems to load and install without problems but when it reboots, I get a black screen. The only thing on the screen is the little network icon and power icon at the top of the screen.

Since eOS is based on Ubuntu, I found instruction on Parallel's website describing a similar problem with Ubuntu server. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work.

Has anyone installed Elementary OS in a Parallels VM? What did you do to get it to work. THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to turn off 3D Acceleration under Graphics - Advanced Options in the config for the VM in Parallels. You can leave Vertical Synchronization checked.

Comment: turning off the 3d acceleration seems to solve the problem but now the system runs very slowly.
is there a fix?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you to both users above for the answer. Yes, that worked to get it to boot.

However, to fix the slowness issues, I had to:

- up the RAM to 4Gb
- up the Video memory to 512Mb
- and set the EFI BIOS option to 64-bit (when building the system)

Yes, running Elementary with the 64-bit BIOS does make a difference!